# Programmatic SQL Beautifier or Reformatter for C#

Tags: c#, sql

I'm looking for a beautifier or reformatter for SQL that is written in C# in order to programmatically beautify my SQL output. It does not need to have colouring, but indention and line breaks would be very nice.

Does anyone know of such a component ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below could be an option for you?

[SqlParser](http://www.sqlparser.com/features/sql-formatter.php)

Comment: Do you know an OpenSource alternative?

Comment: Even it's not an open source component, I will accept your answer, because I don't think that there are any open source alternative out there ... And no other guy answered to my question ... So thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: If you wanted an Open Source solution, it would have been a good idea to include that in the original question...

Answer (score 4):

There is now a new option. Check out NSQLFormatter project. On [Nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/NSQLFormatter) or [Github](https://github.com/mikoskinen/NSQLFormatter-dotnet). 100% Opensource and free.

Comment: This this helped a lot